# PhpUnit + Zend framework - application.config.php: failed to open stream

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I'm just doing some sample with Zend Framework. I created an Album module as the official tutorial said. It works well.
Now I wanted to add Unti testing to this module.
I'm using this guide: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/tutorials/unittesting.html
But at the "A failing test case" chapter I got a different error.

> C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\test>phpunit PHPUnit 3.7.19 by
>   Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> Configuration read from
>   C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\test\phpunit.xml
>
> ←[31;1mE←[0m
>
> Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 8.75Mb
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1)
>   AlbumTest\Controller\AlbumControllerTest::testIndexActionCanBeAccessed
>   include(/var/www/zf2-tutorial/config/application.config.php): failed
>   to open str eam: No such file or directory
>
> C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\test\AlbumTest\Controller\IndexControllerT
>   est.php:14
>   C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\test\AlbumTest\Controller\IndexControllerT
>   est.php:14
>
> ←[37;41m←[2KFAILURES! ←[0m←[37;41m←[2KTests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors:
>   1. ←[0m←[2K

What can be the problem here? I'm searching for a solution, but can find any for this problem yet.

(Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the paths are wrong.

The output says "Configuration read from C:\wamp\www\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\test\phpunit.xml", but the  error message complains about "/var/www/zf2-tutorial/config/application.config.php" not being found.

So the solution would be to change in `AlbumControllerTest`

```
$this->setApplicationConfig(
    include '/var/www/zf2-tutorial/config/application.config.php'
);
```

to

```
$this->setApplicationConfig(
    include 'C:/wamp/www/zf2-tutorial/config/application.config.php'
);
```

or even better (untested):

```
$this->setApplicationConfig(
    include APPLICATION_PATH . '/../config/application.config.php'
);
```

Comment: Wow... thats pretty awkward, becouse I had this idea  few hours ago, but somehow didn't try it...
Btw thx for the answer!

Comment: you're welcome. btw: if the answer did solve your problem, I would appreciate it if you marked it as "accepted answer" :)

Comment: Be sure to make his last solution work. Your C:\ path will fail if you deploy to a linux server